# what is an alternate to len that can be used with float?

Tags: python-2.7

I cant get python to display the number of columns in the array. the rows show up just fine though.

```
def getDataArray1D(filename):
   fileHandle = open(filename, 'r')
   fileData=map(float, fileHandle)  # !!
   fileHandle.close()  
   return fileData

data = getDataArray1D("HEIGHT.csv")    
#print data

rows = len(data)
columns =len(data[0])
print rows, columns
```

Comment: Are you asking for an answer to the title of your question?

Comment: OK, let's think about this. You iterate over a file by lines. If `map(float, fileHandle)` works, then we can deduce that your file is a stack of numbers, one per line. Therefore, the number of columns is... 1. What are you trying to do, really?

Comment: If you're trying to process a real CSV, and not a stack of numbers, I suggest you use [a library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what your question is, but to get the length of the float, you can do

```
def returnLength(number):
    return len(str(number))
```